# using a string path to link list to files, is it the proper implementation?

Tags: c, tree, linked-list

Did I properly get the text file that contains string path, and attain the proper implementation of a link list?
so I can later create a search function, to see if a file is there or not.

text file: path.txt

```
a/a1.txt
a/a2.txt
a/b/b3.txt
a/b/b4.txt
a/c/c4.txt
a/c/c5.txt
a/c/d/d6.txt
a/c/d/g
a/c/d/h
a/c/e/i/i7.txt
a/c/f/j/k/k8.txt
```

code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sMyPath{
        char *element;
        struct sMyPath *next;
} tMyPath;


int main(void)
{
        FILE *pFile;
        pFile = fopen("path.txt", "r");
        char inputstr[1024];
        tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;

//get the text file, and put it into a string inputstr

    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
            while(!feof(pFile))
            {
                    fgets(inputstr, sizeof(inputstr), pFile);
            }
    fclose(pFile);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Could not open the file.\n");
    }
```

//using tokens to get each piece of the string
//seperate directories and text files, put it into a link list

```
    char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
    if(last == NULL){
            //creating node for directory
            first = last = malloc (sizeof (*first));
            first -> element = strdup (token);
            first -> next = NULL;
    } else {
            last -> next = malloc (sizeof (*last));
            last = last -> next;
            last -> element = strdup (token);
            last -> next = NULL;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need us to validate this program that finds whether a file exists among the given list. This looks ok for me except for below reasons,

1)  The linked list you have would contain so many duplicate entries of directories like,

```
a, b, c, d....
```

as the delimiter is '/'. Not sure whether this is what expected.
**Having the delimiter as '\n' would better serve the purpose, IMHO..**

2)  Size of file is fixed. Better do a stat on the file and **allocate memory to hold the file-data**.

3)  **Free**-up memories returned by strdup.